# Read from serial port linux

Tags: c, serial-port

I'm trying to read from serial port, but always get 0 (zero) characters back. Already read the "Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems", but can't find out why the program not waiting (blocking).
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

void main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");

    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
    int n;
    int bytes;

    char c;

    char buffer[10];
    char *bufptr;

    struct termios options;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
    }
    else {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    }

  tcgetattr( fd, &options );

  /* SEt Baud Rate */

  cfsetispeed( &options, B9600 );
  cfsetospeed( &options, B9600 );

  //I don't know what this is exactly

  options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD );

  // Set the Charactor size

  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */

  // Set parity - No Parity (8N1)

  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;

  // Disable Hardware flowcontrol

  //  options.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;  -- not supported

  // Enable Raw Input

  options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

  // Disable Software Flow control

  options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

  // Chose raw (not processed) output

  options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

  if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options ) == -1 )
    printf ("Error with tcsetattr = %s\n", strerror ( errno ) );
  else
    printf ( "%s\n", "tcsetattr succeed" );

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    // Write to the port
    n = write(fd, "1", 1);

    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("write() of 1 bytes failed!\n", stderr);
    }

    // Read from the port

    //fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);

    bytes = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("number of bytes read is %d\n", bytes);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    //perror ("read error:");

    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This information was originally from the Serial Programming Guide<sup>1</sup>.

The reason you are getting a `0` return value is because of this line:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
```

If you want a normal blocking read, unset that flag.

<sub>1. http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html#2_5_4 (now defunct)</sub>

Comment: That ecigs website says nothing about serial communications/programming.

Comment: @josaphatv: It is a dead link now. You can try [this how-to](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/buecher/linuxhackz/Programme/Seriell/linux_serial_mini_howto.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using O_NDELAY

> **O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY**
>
> When possible, the file is opened in non-blocking mode.  Neither the open() nor any subsequent operations on the file
>   descriptor which is returned will  cause  the  calling process to
>   wait.  For the handling of FIFOs (named pipes), see also fifo(7).  For
>   a discussion of the effect of O_NONBLOCK in conjunction with mandatory
>   file locks and with file leases, see fcntl(2).

EDIT: You're doing the same thing in your fcntl() call, as well.